# "eslint-config-react-app" issue with create-react-app version 5

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I have decided to upgrade to the new version of create-react-app and after doing so I tried launching the app via "npm start" and whenever it has loaded onto the screen the error below pops up:

Compiled with problems:X
ERROR
Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » C:\Users\27par\Desktop\React Projects\development\finevines\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » C:\Users\27par\Desktop\React Projects\Development\finevines\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

Image of error:
https://gyazo.com/a03be194379ea52e6d7ddd697eefb8aa

I am wondering if anyone else is having the same issue as me and if there is any possible fix for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update all the packages as in the case of `eslint-config-react-app`'s `package.json` it would have the previous version of `create-react-app`. So, basically the error is telling you that you are updating to the new version, but the other libraries in your project use another version.

Try doing -
`npm run update`

Comment: This seemed to somewhat help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

It is a known issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11825.

[You need to clear your .lock file](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3128#issuecomment-965559013).

Answer (score 1):

Just try running npm update in the terminal being in the root directory of the folder.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for hours today and none of the fixes on here or Github helped me. The only thing that did help me was changing the case of my "Projects" folder to lowercase -> "projects".

I suspect it is a windows specific file naming issue. I would make all of your folder names lowercase and probably not start them with a number. Also, eliminate the spaces in your folder names. I think Git Bash does not like these practices.

Comment: huh. Ill have to try this if the issue ever occurs again!